# Java's equivalent of C++'s string::compare() method

Tags: java, c++, compare

I have tried searching for answers on the internet and read similar questions yet I haven't found a straightforward answer to my question.

Is there a method in Java that is equivalent to C++'s string::compare method?

Comment: **C++ which compare method** ??? there are multiple variant of it !!

Comment: the string compare method

Comment: seems like compareTo would be a close guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `compareTo()` method, which is a lot more similar to your string::compare method.

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString)
```

This method is specified in  **Comparable** interface.

[look at here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))